# What scoring system to use based on two variables

Tags: excel, z-score, scoring-rules

I have an excel file that shows the performance of several keywords in my paid search campaign.
I have two variables, number of visits & conversion rate, based on which I want to score each keyword on a scale from 1-10 or 1-5 (continuous number).

The number of visits take values from 1 until 328 and the conversion rate from 0 to 0.5
i want to use weights as well, meaning that the conversion rate matters more compared to number of visits.

I dont know what method i should use in order to end up with a continuous weighted score for each keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any theoretically “right way” to score this kind of information. The features and consideration you bring up are somewhat subjective in nature. Just using arithmetic we can create a weighted scale such as:

$$\left(\frac{Visits}{328}\times Weight_1+\frac{conversion}{0.5} \times Weight_2\right) \times MaxScore$$
Where: $$Weight_1 +Weight_2 = 1$$

Perhaps I misunderstand your question, feel free to comment.

Comment: thanks ! and in MaxScore, what should it be ?

Comment: should it be the Max of column ''score'' ?

Comment: Max should be whatever you want you maximum score to be. So, either 5 or 10. It doesn't actually matter other than putting it in a convenient scale.

Comment: perfect - thanks! so, ''visits'' & ''conversion'' are the values in the column, weights are the ones that I will decide (as long as adding them i get 1) & the MaxScore is the max of the scale i want to have. right ?